# Multiline text for TToolButton Caption in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a form with a `TToolBar` and two `TToolButton`.

The two buttons are displaying the texts btnFirst and btnSecond using the `TToolButton.Caption` property.

[image: Toolbar with two buttons]

I would like to display the caption with two lines, it would be like a title and a subtitle in the same `TToolButton`. For example:

```
<Question Image>
    btnFirst
    (Ctrl+F)
```

**What have I tried so far?**

I read some question on SO and tried the following things:

1. Set WordWrap for the text.
2. Set Caption to `'btnFirst' + #13#10 + '(Ctrl+F)'`

There is not WordWrap property for `TToolButton`. The button is wraped to its content, it has the size of the image and of the caption, I can not change the size to make it bigger or smaller. Therefore, the second approach does not work because it always wrap to stay in the same line.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Not possible with standard component, you will need to implement [`OnAdvancedCustomDrawButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.OnAdvancedCustomDrawButton) and draw the text yourself

Comment: Consider using hints to display shortcuts, can be multi-line too. Quite common actually..

Comment: And/or a menu for those that want to use the keyboard. Easier and more common (recognisable) to have the shortcut in a menu item caption.